# selecting 5 best players out of 2 team

Tags: algorithm, c, game, linked-list, dynamic-programming

Let us assume that we need to develop an application which can select best 11 players to score maximum points. The application will select the best players after completion of a match.  The rules are mentioned below.

a.  Each cricket team will have 5 players (2 batsmen, 2 bowlers and 1 wicket keeper) only. (For two teams total 10 players)

b.  1 Run means 1 point.  1 wicket means 50 points. Wicketkeepers points will be depend on bowlers. If two bowlers score 100 total points then the points of wicketkeeper will be 50. (50%).

c.  One batsman can score in between 0 to 100 and one bowler can take maximum 3 wickets.

d.  All out is not necessary.  Bowlers cannot score runs.

e.  Points of captain of the fantasy team will be double. That means 1 run = 2 points and 1 wicket = 100 points. The application will automatically select the captain.

f.  One fantasy cricket team can have only one captain.

g.  One can select maximum three players from a team.

h.  Fantasy team can score maximum 200 runs and can take maximum 4 wickets.

1. First create two link lists of two cricket teams (Say team A and team B). Total 5 nodes. The structure of the list is as mentioned below. Put the runs scored by the batsman and wicket taken by the bowler in data field. The points of wicket keepers will be counted automatically as mentioned earlier.

   > Batsman(1)    Batsman(2)  Wicketkeeper    Bowler(1)   Bowler(2)
2. Create a new linklist from above two lists. The data field will represent the team name from where the player belongs. This list will select the best possible 5 players to get the maximum points.
3. Display the fantasy points earn by your selected team.
4. Select the highest run scoring batsman (Select the team) and maximum wicket taking player (Select the team). Select the best valuable wicketkeeper (Select the team). These players may not be present in the selected fantasy cricket team.

   Test Cases: 
   Input: Enter runs score by team ‘A’ batsmen followed by 
      team ‘B’: 29, 81, 79, 35 Enter
      wicket taken by team ‘A’ bowlers followed by 
      team ‘B’: 1, 3, 2, 2
   Output:
        Question 1: Display the two link lists.
        Question 2:  A->B->B->A->A (Result: 81+79+100+150+50) (Captain is a bowler from team A)
   Question 3: Points: 81+79+100+300+50=610
        Question 4: Highest  run scoring batsman is from team A. 
        Highest wicket taking bowler is  from team A. 
        Valuable wicketkeeper is from team B.

My solution for this is following

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<malloc.h>

    /*Structure representing nodes of linked list forming the team. */
    struct Node
    {
            float run;
            struct Node *next;
    };

    /*Function to create a node of a linked list*/
    void create_node(int x,struct Node **temp)
    {
        struct Node *r, *z;
        z = *temp;
        if(z == NULL)
        {
        r =(struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        r->run = x;
        *temp = r;
        r->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        r = r->next;
        r->next = NULL;
        }
        else
        {
        r->run = x;
        r->next = (struct Node*)malloc(sizeof(struct Node));
        r = r->next;
        r->next = NULL;
        }
    }

    /*Function to display the linked lists*/
    void show(struct Node *node)
    {
    while(node->next != NULL)
        {
        printf("%f , ", node->run);
        node = node->next;
        }
    }


    void main()
    {
        struct Node *team1 = NULL , *team2 = NULL , *fteam = NULL ;
        float run1,run2,bow1,bow2,wc1 ;

        printf("Enter the runs and wickets taken by Team-1: \n ");
        printf("Enter the run scored by 1st player of Team-1:");
        scanf("%f" , &run1);
        printf("Enter the run scored by 2nd player of Team-1:");
        scanf("%f" , &run2);
        printf("Enter the wickets taken by 1st bowler player of Team-1:");
        scanf("%f" , &bow1);
        printf("Enter the wickets taken by 2nd bowler player of Team-1:");
        scanf("%f" , &bow2);
        wc1 = ((bow1 + bow2)*50)*0.5 ;

        create_node(run1, &team1);
        create_node(run2, &team1);
        create_node(wc1, &team1);
        create_node(bow1, &team1);
        create_node(bow2, &team1);

        printf("DISPLAY TEAM-1 :");
        show(team1);

        float run21,run22,bow21,bow22,wc2 ;

        printf("\nEnter the runs and wickets taken by Team-2: \n ");
        printf("Enter the run scored by 1st player of Team-2:");
        scanf("%f" , &run21);
        printf("Enter the run scored by 2nd player of Team-2:");
        scanf("%f" , &run22);
        printf("Enter the wickets taken by 1st bowler player of Team-2:");
        scanf("%f" , &bow21);
        printf("Enter the wickets taken by 2nd bowler player of Team-2:");
        scanf("%f" , &bow22);
        wc2 = ((bow21 + bow22)*50)*0.5 ;

        create_node(run21, &team2);
        create_node(run22, &team2);
        create_node(wc2, &team2);
        create_node(bow21, &team2);
        create_node(bow22, &team2);


        printf("\nDISPLAY TEAM-2");
        show(team2);

        float run[4];
        run[0] = run1;
        run[1] = run2;
        run[2] = run21;
        run[3] = run22;

        float bow[4];
        bow[0] = bow1;
        bow[1] = bow2;
        bow[2] = bow21;
        bow[3] = bow22;

        int trun[4];
        int tbow[4];
        int a,b;
        /*Sorting the run array in descending order*/
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
         {
        for (int j = i + 1; j <4;++j)
         {
            if (run[i] < run[j])
            {a = run[i];
             run[i] = run[j];
             run[j] = a;
            }
        }
        }

        /*Checking which Batsman is from which team*/
        if(run[0]==run1 || run[0]==run2)
        {trun[0]=1;}
        else
        {trun[0]=2;}

        if(run[1]==run1 || run[1]==run2)
        {trun[1]=1;}
        else
        {trun[1]=2;}

        if(run[2]==run1 || run[2]==run2)
        {trun[2]=1;}
        else
        {trun[2]=2;}

        if(run[3]==run1 || run[3]==run2)
        {trun[3]=1;}
        else
        {trun[3]=2;}

        /*Sorting the bow array in descending order*/
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
         {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < 4;++j)
         {
            if (bow[i] < bow[j])
            {b = bow[i];
             bow[i] = bow[j];
             bow[j] = b;
            }
        }
        }

        /*Checking which Bowler is from which team*/
        if(bow[0]==bow1 || bow[0]==bow2)
        {tbow[0]=1;}
        else
        {tbow[0]=2;}

        if(bow[1]==bow1 || bow[1]==bow2)
        {tbow[1]=1;}
        else
        {tbow[1]=2;}

        if(bow[2]==bow1 || bow[2]==bow2)
        {tbow[2]=1;}
        else
        {tbow[2]=2;}

        if(bow[3]==bow1 || run[3]==bow2)
        {tbow[3]=1;}
        else
        {tbow[3]=2;}

        float frun1 , frun2 , fbow1 , fbow2 , fwc;
        /*Checking whether the contribution of the team exceeds 3 or not and froming the team*/
        if(trun[0]==trun[1] && tbow[0]==tbow[1] && trun[0]==tbow[0])
        {
            frun1 = run[0];
            frun2 = run[1];
            fbow1 = bow[0];
            fbow2 = bow[2];
            fwc = ((fbow1+fbow2)*50)*0.5;
        }
        else
        {
            frun1 = run[0];
            frun2 = run[1];
            fbow1 = bow[0];
            fbow2 = bow[1];
            fwc = ((fbow1+fbow2)*50)*0.5;

        }

        float ba1 = frun1;
        float ba2 = frun2;
        float bw1 = 50*fbow1 ;
        float bw2 = 50*fbow2 ;

        /*Create the fanntasy league team*/

        create_node(frun1, &fteam);
        create_node(frun2, &fteam);
        create_node(fwc, &fteam);
        create_node(bw1, &fteam);
        create_node(bw2, &fteam);

        /*Dispaly the Fantasy league team*/
        printf("\nFANTASY LEAGUE :");
        show(fteam);

        /*Checking which member is from which team*/
        printf("\n||TEAM SELECTION||");
        if(frun1 == run1 || frun1 == run2)
        {printf("\n1st batsman -> Team-1");}
        else if(frun1 == run21 || frun1 == run22)
        {printf("\n1st batsman -> Team-2");}

        if(frun2 == run1 || frun2 == run2)
        {printf("\n2nd batsman -> Team-1");}
        else if(frun2 == run21 || frun2 == run22)
        {printf("\n2nd batsman -> Team-2");}

        if(wc1>wc2)
        {printf("\nWicket Keeper -> Team-1");}
        else
        {printf("\nWicket Keeper-> Team-2");}

        if(fbow1 == bow1 || fbow1 == bow2)
        {printf("\n1st Bowler -> Team-1");}
        else if(fbow1 == bow21 || fbow1 == bow22)
        {printf("\n1st Bowler -> Team-2");}

        if(fbow2 == bow1 || fbow2 == bow2)
        {printf("\n2nd Bowler -> Team-1");}
        else if(fbow2 == bow21 || fbow2 == bow22)
        {printf("\n2nd Bowler -> Team-2");}

        float arr[5] ;
        arr[0] = ba1;
            arr[1] = ba2;
        arr[2] = fwc;
        arr[3] = bw1;
        arr[4] = bw2;
        float captain;
        captain = arr[0];
            for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        {
            if (arr[i] > captain)
        {
                captain = arr[i];
            }
        }

        float sbow1 = bow1*50;
        float sbow2 = bow2*50;
        float sbow21 = bow21*50;
        float sbow22 = bow22*50;

        printf("\n ||CAPTAIN SELECTION||");
        if(captain == run1)
        {printf("\nCAPTAIN -> 1ST Batsman of TEAM-1");}
        else if(captain == run2)
        {printf("\nCAPTAIN -> 2nd Batsman of TEAM-1");}
        else if(captain == sbow1)
        {printf("\nCAPTAIN -> 1ST Bowler of TEAM-1");}
        else if(captain == sbow2)
        {printf("\nCAPTAIN -> 2nd Bowler of TEAM-1");}
        else if(captain == run21)
        {printf("\nCAPTAIN -> 1ST Batsman of TEAM-2");}
        else if(captain == run22)
        {printf("\nCAPTAIN -> 2nd Batsman of TEAM-2");}
        else if(captain == sbow21)
        {printf("\nCAPTAIN -> 1ST Bowler of TEAM-2");}
        else if(captain == sbow22)
        {printf("\nCAPTAIN -> 2nd Bowler of TEAM-2");}
        else if(captain == fwc)
        {
            if(wc1 > wc2)
            {printf("\nCAPTAIN -> Wicket Keeper of TEAM-1");}
            else
            {printf("\nCAPTAIN -> Wicket Keeper of TEAM-2");}
        }


        float totalscore;
        printf("\n ||TOTAL SCORE||");
        if(captain==frun1)
        {totalscore = (frun1*2)+frun2+(fbow1*50)+(fbow2*50)+fwc;
        printf("\nTotal Score of the FANTASY LEAGUE : %f" , totalscore);
        }

        else if(captain==frun2)
        {totalscore = frun1+(frun2*2)+(fbow1*50)+(fbow2*50)+fwc;
        printf("\nTotal Score of the FANTASY LEAGUE : %f" , totalscore);
        }

        else if(captain==fwc)
        {totalscore = frun1+frun2+(fbow1*50)+(fbow2*50)+fwc;
        printf("\nTotal Score of the FANTASY LEAGUE : %f" , totalscore);
        }

        else if(captain==fwc)
        {totalscore = frun1+frun2+(fbow1*50)+(fbow2*50)+fwc;
        printf("\nTotal Score of the FANTASY LEAGUE : %f" , totalscore);
        }

        else if(captain==bw1)
        {totalscore = frun1+frun2+(fbow1*100)+(fbow2*50)+ (((fbow1*100)+(fbow2*50))*0.5);
        printf("\nTotal Score of the FANTASY LEAGUE : %f" , totalscore);
        }

        else if(captain==bw2)
        {totalscore = frun1+frun2+(fbow1*50)+(fbow2*100)+ (((fbow1*50)+(fbow2*100))*0.5);
        printf("\nTotal Score of the FANTASY LEAGUE : %f" , totalscore);
        }


    }
```

Is there a better way to do as mentioned in question for the problem given above.